# Type I Type II error with power function as y-axis and mu(alternative) as x-axis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, type-i-and-ii-errors

I stuck in the following graph for 2 days. I am confused because I ask myself the following two questions but did not get solved by myself.

Q1: If Null (H0) is larger or equal to 5, then why when mu(alternative) is larger or equal to 5, the area under the curve will be "Type 1 error"? Why would someone reject the Null and commit type 1 error if we set mu(alternative) is within the Null's claimed range (i.e. larger or equal to 5)?

Q2: Why when the p(mu alternative), the y-axis, is nearly 1, which means if the mu(alternative) is truly 4, then the probability of rejecting the Null is nearly 1, used "Type II error" instead of "Type 1 error"? If we can reject the null when mu(alternative) = 4, then why don't we use "Type 1 error" to represent the area under the curve?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The area is irrelevant: you are misreading the figure (which is, I readily admit, quite ambiguous).  One way to confirm that the area is meaningless would be to rescale the x-axis.  Suppose, for instance, $\mu_\alpha$ is a length in meters and instead you change it to millimeters.  This multiplies everything on that axis by 1,000, making the area of the "Type II error" region hugely greater than 1.  Obviously, then, *that area cannot be an error rate.*

Comment: What do you mean by the area is irrelevant? I think it makes sense seems when the mu(alternative) gets closer to mu(null) which is 5, then we are more likely can't reject mu(null) even mu(alternative) is true and therefore the Type II error, the grey area, gets near to 1.